# How to handle Angular HttpClient.post return as string?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

All the examples I found in web are like this:

```
createArticle(article: Article): Observable<Article> {
     return this.http.post<Article>(this.url, article);
}
```

so they assume that web API's response contains Article. How to write above so that an Article is posted to web API and the response is string?

Answer (score 5):

I came across [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18586#issuecomment-327417876) solution which solved the problem perfectly for me.

changing the return type is not enough, you need to add headers to your requst as bellow:

```
 createArticle(article: Article): Observable<any> {
    
        var headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=utf-8');
    
        return this.http.post<any>(this._url, article, { headers, responseType: 'text' as 'json' })
            .pipe(catchError(err => {
                console.log(err);
                return Observable.throw(err);
            }));
}
```